# error: redefinition of ' '

Tags: arduino-uno

When I am trying to compile the following code,

```
int delayTime = 1;
int charBreak = 2.1;
#include <MemoryFree.h>

int rled1 = 1;
int rled2 = 2;
int rled3 = 3;
int rled4 = 4;
int rled5 = 5;
int gled1 = 6;
int gled2 = 7;
int gled3 = 8;
int gled4 = 9;
int gled5 = 10;
int bled1 = 11;
int bled2 = 12;
int bled3 = 13;
int bled4 = 14;
int bled5 = 15;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

int ra[] = {4,288,18464,288,4};
int ga[] = {2,144,9232,144,2};
int ba[] = {1,72,4616,72,2};
int rb[] = {18724,16644,16644,2080,0};
int gb[] = {9362,8322,8322,1040,0};
int bb[] = {4681,4161,4161,520,0};
int rc[] = {2336,16388,16388,2080,0};
int gc[] = {1168,8194,8194,1040,0};
int bc[] = {584,4097,4097,520,0};
int rd[] = {18724,16388,16388,2336,0};
int gd[] = {9362,8194,8194,1168,0};
int bd[] = {4681,4097,4097,584,0};
int re[] = {18724,16644,16644,16388,0};
int ge[] = {9362,8322,8322,8194,0};
int be[] = {4681,4161,4161,4097,0};
int rf[] = {18724,16640,16640,16384,0};
int gf[] = {9362,8320,8320,8192,0};
int bf[] = {4681,4160,4160,4096,0};
int rg[] = {2336,16388,16420,16416,2084};
int gg[] = {1168,8194,8210,8208,1042};
int bg[] = {584,4097,4105,4104,521};
int rh[] = {18724,256,256,256,18724};
int gh[] = {9362,128,128,128,9362};
int bh[] = {4681,64,64,64,4681};
int ri[] = {0,16388,18724,16388,0};
int gi[] = {0,8194,9362,8194,0};
int bi[] = {0,4097,4681,4097,0};
int rj[] = {32,4,16388,18720,16384};
int gj[] = {16,2,8194,9360,8192};
int bj[] = {8,1,4097,4680,4096};
int rk[] = {18724,256,2080,16388,0};
int gk[] = {9362,128,1040,8194,0};
int bk[] = {4681,64,520,4097,0};
int rl[] = {18724,4,4,4,0};
int gm[] = {9362,2,2,2,0};
int bm[] = {4681,1,1,1,0};
int rm[] = {18724,2304,36,2304,18724};
int gm[] = {9362,1152,18,1152,9362};
int bm[] = {4681,576,9,576,4681};
int rn[] = {18724,2304,36,18724,0};
int gn[] = {9362,1152,18,9362,0};
int bn[] = {4681,576,9,4681,0};
int ro[] = {2336,16388,16388,2336,0};
int go[] = {1168,8194,8194,1168,0};
int bo[] = {584,4097,4097,584,0};
int rp[] = {18724,16640,16640,2048,0};
int gp[] = {9362,8320,8320,1024,0};
int bp[] = {4681,4160,4160,512,0};
int rq[] = {2336,16388,16420,2336,36};
int gq[] = {1168,8194,8210,1168,18};
int bq[] = {584,4097,4105,584,9};
int rr[] = {18724,16640,16672,2052,0};
int gr[] = {9362,8320,8336,1026,0};
int br[] = {4681,4160,4168,513,0};
int rs[] = {2048,16644,16644,32,0};
int gs[] = {1024,8322,8322,16,0};
int bs[] = {512,4161,4161,8,0};
int rt[] = {16384,16384,18724,16384,16384};
int gt[] = {8192,8192,9362,8192,8192};
int bt[] = {4096,4096,4681,4096,4096};
int ru[] = {18720,4,4,18720,0};
int gu[] = {9360,2,2,9360,0};
int bu[] = {4680,1,1,4680,0};
int rv[] = {18432,288,4,288,18432};
int gv[] = {9216,144,2,144,9216};
int bv[] = {4608,72,1,72,4608};
int rw[] = {18688,36,2304,36,18688};
int gw[] = {9344,18,1152,18,9344};
int bw[] = {4672,9,576,9,4672};
int rx[] = {16388,2080,256,2080,16388};
int gx[] = {8194,1040,128,1040,8194};
int bx[] = {4097,520,64,520,4097};
int ry[] = {16388,2080,256,2048,16384};
int gy[] = {8194,1040,128,1024,8192};
int by[] = {4097,520,64,512,4096};
int rz[] = {16420,16644,16644,18436,0};
int gz[] = {8210,8322,8322,9218,0};
int bz[] = {4105,4161,4161,4609,0};
int reos[] = {0,4,0,0,0};
int geos[] = {0,2,0,0,0};
int beos[] = {0,1,0,0,0};
int rque[] = {2048,16420,16640,2048,0};
int gque[] = {1024,8210,8320,1024,0};
int bque[] = {512,4105,4160,512,0};
int rexcl[] = {0,18692,0,0,0};
int gexcl[] = {0,9346,0,0,0};
int bexcl[] = {0,4673,0,0,0};

void displayLine(int line)
{
  int myline; myline = line;
  if (myline>=16384) {digitalWrite(rled1, HIGH); myline-=16384;} else {digitalWrite(rled1, LOW);}
  if (myline>=8192) {digitalWrite(gled1, HIGH); myline-=8192;} else {digitalWrite(gled1, LOW);}
  if (myline>=4096) {digitalWrite(bled1, HIGH); myline-=4096;} else {digitalWrite(bled1, LOW);}
  if (myline>=2048) {digitalWrite(rled2, HIGH); myline-=2048;} else {digitalWrite(rled2, LOW);}
  if (myline>=1024) {digitalWrite(gled2, HIGH); myline-=1024;} else {digitalWrite(gled2, LOW);}
  if (myline>=512) {digitalWrite(bled2, HIGH); myline-=512;} else {digitalWrite(bled2, LOW);}
  if (myline>=256) {digitalWrite(rled3, HIGH); myline-=256;} else {digitalWrite(rled3, LOW);}
  if (myline>=128) {digitalWrite(gled3, HIGH); myline-=128;} else {digitalWrite(gled3, LOW);}
  if (myline>=64) {digitalWrite(bled3, HIGH); myline-=64;} else {digitalWrite(bled3, LOW);}
  if (myline>=32) {digitalWrite(rled4, HIGH); myline-=32;} else {digitalWrite(rled4, LOW);}
  if (myline>=16) {digitalWrite(gled4, HIGH); myline-=16;} else {digitalWrite(gled4, LOW);}
  if (myline>=8) {digitalWrite(bled4, HIGH); myline-=8;} else {digitalWrite(bled4, LOW);}
  if (myline>=4) {digitalWrite(rled5, HIGH); myline-=4;} else {digitalWrite(rled5, LOW);}
  if (myline>=2) {digitalWrite(gled5, HIGH); myline-=2;} else {digitalWrite(gled5, LOW);}
  if (myline>=1) {digitalWrite(bled5, HIGH); myline-=1;} else {digitalWrite(bled5, LOW);}

}

void displayChar(char c)
{
  if (c == 'ra'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(ra[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'rb'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(rb[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'rc'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(rc2[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'rd'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(rd[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 're'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(re[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'rf'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(rf[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'rg'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(rg[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'rh'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(rh[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'ri'){for (int it = 0; it <5; it++){displayLine(ri[it]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'rj'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(rj[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'rk'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(rk[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'rl'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(rl[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'rm'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(rm[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'rn'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(rn[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'ro'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(ro[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'rp'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(rp[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'rq'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(rq[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'rr'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(rr[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'rs'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(rs[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'rt'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(rt[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'ru'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(ru[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'rv'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(rv[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'rw'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(rw[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'rx'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(rx[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'ry'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(ry[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'rz'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(rz[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'r!'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(rexcl[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'r?'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(rques[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'r.'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(reos[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'ga'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(ga[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'gb'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(gb[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'gc'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(gc2[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'gd'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(gd[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'ge'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(ge[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'gf'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(gf[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'gg'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(gg[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'gh'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(gh[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'gi'){for (int it = 0; it <5; it++){displayLine(gi[it]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'gj'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(gj[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'gk'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(gk[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'gl'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(gl[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'gm'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(gm[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'gn'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(gn[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'go'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(go[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'gp'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(gp[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'gq'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(gq[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'gr'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(gr[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'gs'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(gs[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'gt'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(gt[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'gu'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(gu[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'gv'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(gv[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'gw'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(gw[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'gx'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(gx[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'gy'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(gy[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'gz'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(gz[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'g!'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(gexcl[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'g?'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(gques[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'g.'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(geos[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'ba'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(ba[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'bb'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(bb[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'bc'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(bc2[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'bd'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(bd[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'be'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(be[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'bf'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(bf[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'bg'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(bg[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'bh'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(bh[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'bi'){for (int it = 0; it <5; it++){displayLine(bi[it]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'bj'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(bj[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'bk'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(bk[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'bl'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(bl[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'bm'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(bm[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'bn'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(bn[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'bo'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(bo[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'bp'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(bp[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'bq'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(bq[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'br'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(br[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'bs'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(bs[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'bt'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(bt[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'bu'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(bu[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'bv'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(bv[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'bw'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(bw[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'bx'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(bx[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'by'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(by[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'bz'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(bz[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'b!'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(bexcl[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'b?'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(bques[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  if (c == 'b.'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(beos[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
  delay(charBreak);
}

void displayString(char* s)
{
  for (int i = 0; i<=strlen(s); i++)
  {
  displayChar(s[i]);
  }
}

void loop()
{
  displayString("sunil");
  Serial.print("freeMemory()=");
    Serial.println(freeMemory());
}
```

I am getting the following error.

```
sketch_jul17b:63: error: redefinition of 'int gm []'
sketch_jul17b:60: error: 'int gm [5]' previously defined here
sketch_jul17b:64: error: redefinition of 'int bm []'
sketch_jul17b:61: error: 'int bm [5]' previously defined here
sketch_jul17b.ino: In function 'void displayChar(char)':
sketch_jul17b:139: error: 'rc2' was not declared in this scope
sketch_jul17b:164: error: 'rques' was not declared in this scope
sketch_jul17b:168: error: 'gc2' was not declared in this scope
sketch_jul17b:177: error: 'gl' was not declared in this scope
sketch_jul17b:193: error: 'gques' was not declared in this scope
sketch_jul17b:197: error: 'bc2' was not declared in this scope
sketch_jul17b:206: error: 'bl' was not declared in this scope
sketch_jul17b:222: error: 'bques' was not declared in this scope
```

I don't know why this error is occurring.

Comment: Redefining variable names is a huge reason to avoid meaningless names like you're using. Use names like "RedLedPinNumber" and "RedLedCurrentState" and "GreenLedCurrentState" - MUCH easier to remember if you created one of those already. Variables take up the same amount of memory regardless of their names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a combination of trying to define the same name twice, for example "gm"

```
int gm[] = {9362,2,2,2,0};
int bm[] = {4681,1,1,1,0};
int rm[] = {18724,2304,36,2304,18724};
int gm[] = {9362,1152,18,1152,9362};
```

And using others such "rc2" which you have never defined.

Your code won't compile and work until you make it self-consistent.

Comment: Please note that user2973 has found some additional problems in your code beyond the error messages you posted.

Answer (score 8):

This can also happen if you have saved a version of the code (for example duplicate file for backup) within the current sketch folder.

Comment: Thanks, Bruno. Strangely enough, this was my problem with the example of a downloaded library that had the same example saved with .ino and .pde extensions. Deleted the .pde and worked fine.

Comment: No worries, thanks for the comment! I knew this was going to help some-one as it is an easy mistake to make. (I did it when I duplicated the file inside the sketch folder. This would be the same as creating a tab page inside the IDE so the code is double defined. Which is the same problem as the original question. Hence the same error.

Answer (score 3):

The first errors happen because you are trying to define a variable with the same name in the same scope twice, like here:

```
int gm[] = {9362,2,2,2,0};
int bm[] = {4681,1,1,1,0};
int rm[] = {18724,2304,36,2304,18724};
int gm[] = {9362,1152,18,1152,9362};
```

gm is defined two times which is not allowed.

The other error happens because you are referencing variables you never declared like here:

```
if (c == 'rc'){for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){displayLine(rc2[i]);delay(delayTime);}displayLine(0);}
```

rc2 isn't defined anywhere.

---

Besides there are some other issues with your code:

```
int charBreak = 2.1;
```

`int` types can only contain whole numbers, so `charBreak` will be set to two and not two point one. You probably wan't to use a `float`.

In `void displayChar(char c)` you try to compare a char with two chars:

```
if (c == 'ra')
```

That won't work. The char type can only contain a single character, so the comparison will always be false. Two chars like this `'ab'` in single quotes are interpreted as 16 bit number. Two chars in double quotes are interpreted as a null-terminated string:

```
char cstring1[] = "ab";
char cstring2[] = {'a', 'b', '\0'};

if (strcmp(cstring1, cstring2) == 0)
  // The two strings are identical
```

`strcmp` returns 0 on match-.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help with comparing characters. I was actually stuck there.